# React "cannot access 'variable' before initialization" with useState callback

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use a callback with useState but am running into this issue

```js
export default function Dropdown(props) {
    const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false);

    const [values, setSelectedValues] = useState(props.values);

    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = 
        useState(props.defaultIndex, runCallback())

    function runCallback() {
        props.callback({value: values[selectedIndex], index: selectedIndex})
    }

    function handleClick() {
        setDropdown(!dropdown);
    }
    function dropdownOnClick(index){
        setSelectedIndex(index);
        setDropdown(!dropdown);
    }
```

There is other code but it's just the html and the debugger is pointing me specifically to the line with `props.callback`. I've been searching for a while and can't find an answer to this specific problem

Comment: `function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];` react `useState` doesn't accept a second callback.

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to respond but I'm not quite sure what you mean by a second callback. Do you simply mean useState doesn't appreciate calling an external function inside callback function?

Comment: What @HenokTesfaye is saying is that `useState` only accepts one parameter, either a value for the initial state, or a callback function for that same initial state. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with `useState(props.defaultIndex, runCallback())`.

Comment: No, it definitely accepts multiple parameters. I have absolutely no issue with setting the default parameter to a different index while still passing a function for it to callback. The default parameter changes accordingly and `runCallback()` is still called whenever the value is update. (Side note, I don't know how I missed a naming error but as far as code is concerned, it still works, just makes it a little confusing to read.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to pretend I understand what the heck is going on however I found that changing my `runCallback()` function to an async function and adding `await 1` to the top of it, I was able to get it to work just fine.

```js
export default function Dropdown(props) {
    const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false);

    const [values, setSelectedValues] = useState(props.values);

    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = 
        useState(props.defaultIndex, runCallback())

    async function runCallback() {
        await 1;
        props.callback({value: values[selectedIndex], index: selectedIndex})
    }

    function handleClick() {
        setDropdown(!dropdown);
    }
    function dropdownOnClick(index){
        setSelectedIndex(index);
        setDropdown(!dropdown);
    }
```

When I simply changed `runCallback` to an async function, `selectedIndex` was always coming up as undefined. I thought that maybe something in useState hadn't finished yet? I don't really know so I just added a small `await 1` inside and now I'm able to call the external function with the updated values no problem.

I had tried directly calling the function I passed in `props.callback` however I still ran into the same issue of selectedIndex not being initialized.